# Display gif after confirm until loading is finished in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that includes a Submit button.  After the submit button is clicked, a confirmation popup appears.  Once the confirm condition is met, an HTTP post takes place.  However, sometimes that post can take a while.  As such, I would like to display a loading gif after the confirm condition is met, up until the post response comes back, whereby the page is already reloading.

Comment: Add an event handler that shows the image when the button is clicked

Comment: And then add another event handler to remove the image when the response comes back.   ;)

Comment: Can you provide a simple example?  There is no event handler on the confirm..

Comment: https://codepen.io/hdl881127/pen/VbarEE yo can do something like this, I used this on my web app, after submit do validation if valid submit the form and show this loading screen, after form submitted redirect user to confirm page. done

Comment: The submit button has already been clicked.  At that point a whole bunch of form validation takes place.  If it doesn't pass, a confirm dialogue appears telling them to fix the mistake.  If it does pass, a confirm dialogue appears asking if they are sure they want to submit.  Here is where I want the loading, as the server response can take a while.  After the response comes back, another confirm dialogue appears telling them it was successful.

Comment: @slashnburn something like this? It will validate if the number is xx.x you can put 11.123 and it will stop submit. https://codepen.io/hdl881127/pen/VbarEE, Note you can put anything inside that jQuery submit event, `appendTo` a gif is also easy.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using an element as some sort of modal then setting the css property [`visibility`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp) to and from `hidden` and `visible`.

Then you can add event handlers to your button presses and requests to hide or show this element.

See the example below:

```js
const requestButton = document.querySelector('.request');
const yes = document.querySelector('.yes');
const no = document.querySelector('.no');
const confirmation = document.querySelector('.confirmation');
const loading = document.querySelector('.loading');
const content = document.querySelector('.content');

requestButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
  confirmation.style.visibility = 'visible';
});

yes.addEventListener('click', event => {
  // instead of a setTimeout, you'd actually make a request using `fetch` or jquery ajax
  loading.style.visibility = 'visible';
  confirmation.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    // the code in this callback would be the same code you'd put in your `success` callback
    // i.e. this code should run when the request finishes
    loading.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    const p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerText = 'Loaded!';
    content.appendChild(p);
  }, 2000);
});

no.addEventListener('click', event => {
  confirmation.style.visibility = 'hidden';
});
```

```css
.hidden-center {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.modal {
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 3em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="content">
  <button class="request">load a thingy?</button>
</div>
<div class="confirmation hidden-center">
  <div class="modal">
    Are you sure?
    <div>
      <button class="yes">Yes</button>
      <button class="no">No</button></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="loading hidden-center">
  <div class="modal">
    <div>Loading...</div>
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

Reading the comments above, it looks like your application is not a single page application (I just assume nowadays). Instead of attaching an event listener to the button click, you need to attach the event listener to the form like so:

```
document.querySelector('#my-form-id').addEventListener('submit', event => {/*code to show loading*/})
```

Also, you probably don't need to add an event listener for the request coming back because the new document will replace the current one.

Comment: I will give this a shot!  Thank you!

Comment: @slashnburn reading the comments above, it looks like your application is not a single page application (I just assume nowadays). Now you need to attach the event listener to the form. instead of adding the event listener to the button click, add it to the form on the `submit` event like so: `yourForm.addEventListener('submit', event => {/*code to show loading*/})`. And also, you probably don't need to add an event listener on the request coming back because the new document will replace the current one

Comment: updated the answer to reflect what I said in the comment

Comment: Thanks for this code! I put class="request" to a submit button. Now how do I return true/false when I clicked yes/no? co'z it always submits the page.